# every sequential $KC$ space $(X,\tau)$ has FDS property

Tags: general-topology, convergence-divergence

A space is said to have the finite derived set property
(hereafter abbreviated as the FDS-property) if each infinite subset $A ⊂ X$ contains
an infinite subset with only finitely many accumulation points in $X$.

A topological space is called a sequential space if a set
$A ⊂ X$ is closed if and only if together with any sequence it contains all its limits.

A
topological space $(X,\tau)$ is called a $KC$-space if every compact subset is closed.

> **Why we can say that every sequential $KC$ space $(X,\tau)$ has FDS property?**

Comment: Does it make sense to answer you? Since you have never reacted to any answer (with none of your profiles).

Comment: @user87690: For me it does, simply because the topic is both new and interesting to me; it just isn't an especially high priority.

Comment: I agree, it's a sort of fun subject, but I don't have too much time to immerse myself in it.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\cl}{\operatorname{cl}}$Let $X$ be a sequential $KC$ space, and let $A$ be an arbitrary infinite subset of $X$. If every infinite subset of $A$ is closed in $X$, then $A$ is a closed, discrete set in $X$ and therefore has no accumulation points. Otherwise, let $B$ be an infinite subset of $A$ that is not closed. The fact that $X$ is sequential ensures that there are an $x\in(\cl B)\setminus B$ and a sequence $\langle x_n:n\in\omega\rangle$ in $B$ converging to $x$. Let $D=\{x_n:n\in\omega\}$; then $D\cup\{x\}$ is compact and therefore closed. We've seen before in this setting that no $x_n$ can be an accumulation point of $D$, so $x$ is the only accumulation point of $D$. It follows that $X$ has the $FDS$ property.